How do I remove spaces after tabs and at the end of each line
I tried using a couple of methods but they didn't help me.
Here I have the string type LastNameEmployee   task
After the employee's last name, there is a tab and a space (I need to remove this space and leave the tab)
I also have to put a space at the end of each line, it also needs to be removed
 private void ProcessTrackerFile(string filePath)
 {
     string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
     var updatedLines = new List<string>();
     var taskCountPerTracker = new Dictionary<string, int>();

     foreach (string line in lines)
     {
         string[] fields = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
         if (fields.Length >= 7)
         {
             string trackerId = fields[5].Trim();
             if (TrackerDictionary.ContainsKey(trackerId))
             {
                 string trackerName = TrackerDictionary[trackerId];
                 fields[5] = trackerName;
                 fields[0] = fields[5];
                 fields[5] = "";
                 fields[4] = "";

                 // Увеличиваем счетчик задач для данного трекера
                 if (taskCountPerTracker.ContainsKey(trackerName))
                 {
                     taskCountPerTracker[trackerName]++;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     taskCountPerTracker[trackerName] = 1;
                 }
             }
         }

         string updatedLine = string.Join(",", fields);
         updatedLines.Add(updatedLine);
     }

     // Перемешивание строк
     var random = new Random();
     updatedLines = updatedLines.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToList();

     string newFilePathT = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), "Tracker_task_" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
     File.WriteAllLines(newFilePathT, updatedLines);

     string content = CleanContent(File.ReadAllText(newFilePathT));

     foreach (var trackerName in TrackerDictionary.Values)
     {
         string regexPattern = @"\b" + Regex.Escape(trackerName) + @"\b";
         content = Regex.Replace(content, regexPattern, "\r\n" + trackerName + "\t");
     }

     File.WriteAllText(newFilePathT, content);

     if (taskCountPerTracker.Any())
     {
         var firstValue = taskCountPerTracker.First().Value;
         tasksCountContent.AppendLine($"class_weights = {{ ");

         foreach (var entry in taskCountPerTracker)
         {
             double calculatedValue = (100.0 / ((entry.Value * 100.0) / firstValue));
             tasksCountContent.AppendLine($" \"{entry.Key}\": {calculatedValue.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)},"); ;
         }
         tasksCountContent.AppendLine($"}}");

         File.WriteAllText(tasksCountFilePath, tasksCountContent.ToString());
     }
     else
     {
         // Обработка ситуации, когда словарь пуст
         Console.WriteLine("Словарь taskCountPerTracker пуст. Невозможно вычислить firstValue.");
     }
 }

Here is a function that cleans the code from unnecessary characters:
private string CleanContent(string content)
{
    content = Regex.Replace(content, "<.*?>|</.*?>", " ").Trim();
    content = Regex.Replace(content, @"(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})+(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})?)", " ").Trim();
    content = Regex.Replace(content, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-Я\r\n\s]", " ").Trim();
    content = Regex.Replace(content, @"\b[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9]\b", " ").Trim();

    // Удаление ненужных слов
    string[] wordsToRemove = { "Добрый день", "Коллеги", "Прошу", "Спасибо", "Доброе утро", "Добрый вечер", "Здравствуйте", "прилагаю", "скриншот", "картинку" };
    foreach (var word in wordsToRemove)
    {
        content = content.Replace(word, " ").Trim();
    }

    // Удаление остатков html сокращений
    content = content.Replace("&nbsp;", " ").Replace("&quot;", " ").Replace("&lt;", " ").Replace("&gt;", " ").Trim();

    // Замена 2 и более пробелов на 1 пробел
    content = Regex.Replace(content, @"\s+", " ").Trim();


    return content;
}

I tried adding a method of type
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"\s+$", "").Trim();


"I also have to put a space at the end of each line, it also needs to be removed" - this contradicts itself?

The code you posted seems to do a lot more than the task you described. Can you provide a minimal code example?

With input text LastNameEmployee\t task and the goal being 1. replace \t  with '\t' and append a space, using LINQ Select, a simple text Replace and append would work:
var t = new string[]{ "LastNameEmployee\t task", "a\t b", "c\t d", };
var r = t.Select(x => x.Replace("\t ", "\t") + " ").ToArray();

